# Intellij 2019 recompile whole classes problem

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

I was using Intellij 2018. A week ago ı've updated it to Intellij 2019. But after update, even if i did not any change on project and try to rerun the project. Intellij 2019 starts to recompile whole classes. Is there any option to disable this or is this a known bug.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Try to disable the step of Build before running, on the Run/Debug Configuration Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2VJq.png)

Comment: Build is enabled also in 2018 but it cause no problem. I think this is not problem.